# How to align on same line 2 equations with MathJax

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mathjax

I would like to align the 2 below equations on the same line with MathJax :

```
\begin{equation}
  H_{x}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 -1 & -2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  H_{y}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -2 & 0 & 2\\ 
 -1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

I tried with `\begin{align}` and `\begin{multicols}{2}` but none works with MathJax.

Anyone could have a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: as in latex just delete the middle `\end{equation}\begin{equation}`

Comment: [See this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n4onr.png)...

Comment: close voters: I see no reason to close a question off topic just because it mentions mathjax if the question and answer apply equally to latex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mathjax-specific questions are off topic but the markup here is just as in latex, and the answer is the same, you want one `equation` environment not two

```
\begin{equation}
  H_{x}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 -1 & -2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
%\end{equation}
\qquad
%\begin{equation}
  H_{y}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -2 & 0 & 2\\ 
 -1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```